# Opening template project with PyQGIS in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgs, template

What do I need to do to open a project-file as a template with PyQGIS in QGIS 3?

I am able to open a project like this:

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read('C:/path/to/my/project.qgs')
```

But how do I open this `"project.qgs"` as a template-project?

Comment: What is your objective or meaning of template, can you expand more?