# What PyQGIS signal is emitted when creating a New Empty Project in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm following a [tutorial](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/pyqgis-in-a-day.html#exercise-4), trying to use startup.py to change the main window title at startup and when new projects are opened. My code works in every circumstance (that I've checked), except when clicking on the New Empty Project option in the Project Templates section of the QGIS home.

[image]

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import QgsExpressionContextUtils

def customize():
    version = QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalScope().variable('qgis_version')
    title = 'QGIS'
    iface.mainWindow().setWindowTitle('{} | {}'.format(title, version))
    
iface.initializationCompleted.connect(customize)
iface.newProjectCreated.connect(customize)
iface.projectRead.connect(customize)
```

What signal is emitted when the new project is created from a template? There are no other relevant `QgisInterface` [signals](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/gui/other/QgisInterface.html) that I can see.

I believe this is related to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308311/opening-template-project-with-pyqgis-in-qgis-3), but that question has no answers.

I also tried using the `customVariablesChanged` signal based on the answer to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381917/emitting-signal-when-project-property-is-changed-using-pyqgis) but it has no effect when opening the template.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `newProject`: "Start a blank project".

Comment: `newProject` produces an error on startup `iface.newProject.connect(customize)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'connect'`